# Is it wise to have if logic inside a python catch block?

Tags: python, try-catch, catch-block

Consider the following method that checks if a parameter contains a valid UUID string and generates a new one if it isn't and if the option is set:

```
def validate_uuid(val, generate):
    try:
        uuid.UUID(str(val))
        return val
    except ValueError:
        if generate:
            return str(uuid.uuid4())
        raise
```

I feel that for this particular use-case, having a small simple condition inside the catch block makes sense, however, I would like to understand if there's possibly a better way that adheres to pythonic principles.

Comment: Well, I think the biggest issue is why *validate* method needs to return the value it receives as parameter in the first place.

Comment: Perfectly fine to have logic inside `except`.

Comment: @matszwecja I understand your point. This method is actually being used in a pandas `apply` though so it has to return something.

Answer (score 3):

Your function is not reuturning the processed uuid in the happy case:

```
def validate_uuid(val, generate):
    try:
        # uuid.UUID(str(val))
        # return val
        # ^^^^^^^^^^ this just returns the original value

        # try returning directly
        return uuid.UUID(str(val))

    except ValueError:
        if generate:
            return str(uuid.uuid4())
        raise
```

But to answer your question, in this small function its probably not too harmful, although it takes a bit of thinking to figure out whats going on. Theres also a naming issue; to a user (perhaps yourself, in the future), importing the `validate_uuid` function, you might be surprised that it can also generate different ones. The generate parameter does imply whats going on but will cause you to have to stop and think.

It's probably better practice to keep the logic outside of the error handling. One option could be to split the function in two and take the chance to give them more meaningful names:

```
def validate_uuid(val):
    return uuid.UUID(str(val))


def validate_or_create_uuid(val):
    try:
        return validate_uuid(val)
    except ValueError:
        return str(uuid.uuid4())
```

If you just want a function to raise an error if any string is not a correctly formed uuid then no need to return at all. Or you could use the try/except logic to return a boolean.

```
def raise_for_invalid_uuid(val):
    uuid.UUID(val)


def is_valid_uuid(val):
    try:
        uuid.UUID(str(val))
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Comment: For the first method, ideally I'd like to use pandas `apply` though to make a check on a specific column. I'm thinking this would work except that I return the original `val` string instead of it transformed into a `uuid` type.